# How do I pxeboot all of ubuntu onto a computer without any i/o exept ethernet (and keyboard) while without an hd?

Tags: boot, ethernet, pxe, tftp

I have an old Vaio computer that was going to be thrown out because it has a faulty hard drive, and no i/o ports work except the ethernet (and the keyboard). (Note: I know that it is possible to change the hd, but that is not my question)

What my goal is: to boot ubuntu onto the computer using pxeboot (w/o any hd).

I was able to boot the ubuntu installer by using tftp on my other windows computer using instructions that I found on google somewhere. This was good, however, the computer does not have a hard drive, so I cannot install it there.

What I am asking is: do any of you know how to boot the entire ubuntu os (as you could with a usb dongle) only using pxeboot over ethernet? I only want ubuntu to RUN on the computer. I do not want it to be installed. Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Just curious. How would you be able to *use* Ubuntu after you've accomplished a PXE boot? Since there's no I/O I guess there's no way to operate it (no keyboard/mouse). Or do you plan to do this over the network somehow?

Comment: Do you have knowledge on setting up iSCSI or NFS? And have you every chrooted/debootstrapped for example? It's not the easiest task in the world for a novice user, but doable if willing to learn.

Comment: Well, its sort of an experiment. Once I get an os onto it, it might be worth changing out the i/o connections.

Comment: (reply to gertvdijk) No, I don't. Let me take a look at it on google. Yes i'm definitely willing to learn. It took everything i've got to even get the pxeboot to work on tftp because the files all got mixed up.

Comment: I took a look at iSCSI, NFS, chroot, and debootstrap on Wikipedia, but I would need directions on how to install/use them for what i'm trying to do. I'm not a newbie when it comes to this type of computer stuff, but I would appreciate some confidence in what I am doing (step-by-step instructions).

Comment: [Ubuntu Community Wiki: DisklessUbuntuHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto)

Comment: Oh boy... That's a whole lot! Is there a way to serve the os originally from a windows computer?

Comment: You know what, i'll attempt the method you linked too. In the mean time, if you could, make sure that there isn't an easier method. (Maybe using windows or something). Thanks for all your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: There's not a point and click solution to this, I'm afraid. It's quite advanced and requires some skills. Windows Server can do NFS and iSCSI nowadays, but I'd set up a virtual machine on a Windows PC to do this. Anyway, this is getting nowhere as a Q&A and would suit a lot better on discussion forums in my opinion. I've done this diskless persistent installations before and running it regularly, but it requires too much time to write half a book as the answer, sorry.

Comment: Oh...That's alright. Does the guide that you linked to follow much of your formula?

Comment: NOTE: I said no i/o, but I didn't think of the keyboard as an i/o. THE COMPUTER IS FULLY OPERATIONAL EXCEPT FOR NO HD OR ANY OTHER CONNECTION PORTS EXCEPT ETHERNET. THE KEYBOARD WORKS FINE. THE SCREEN WORKS FINE. ITS JUST A SMALL PROJECT I HAD.